# How to get a list of all changed files during one git filter-branch --tree-filter step

Tags: git, bash

I'm doing a complex `git filter-branch` with a `--tree-filter` in an external script. In that script, I may add, delete, or move files, depending on certain conditions. The end result of one particular filtered commit may be, that, compared to the previous commit, only one specific file would change. Let's call that file `foo`. If only `foo` is changed, then there should be no change at all, resulting in a commit with an empty changeset, which would be removed by the `--prune-empty` option.

With `git ls-files --modified --others` you can find out which files are modified (added, changed, removed). This works as expected in normal interactive git operation, but yields an unexpected result during filter-branch.

I started out with

```
if [ -f foo ]; then
    UpdateFoo
fi
```

(If the file `foo` exists, then execute `UpdateFoo`)

I changed that to

```
CHANGED=$(git ls-files --modified --others)
if [ -f foo -a "$CHANGED" != "foo" ]; then
    UpdateFoo
fi
```

**Expected result**

The intention here being that `UpdateFoo` is not executed when the value of `$CHANGED` is *exactly* equal to `foo`, i.e. `foo` is the only file in the changeset.

**Actual result**

During filter-branch, `$CHANGED` contains all the files in the commit, so I end up with commits where `foo` is the only changed file.

How can I get a list of all changed files during one filter-branch step?

**EDIT**

I have an idea, that I have not yet implemented, and that will most likely double the time needed to run the script. The current iteration takes about 20 minutes to filter ~800 commits.

- at the end of the tree-filter script, copy the working directory to a temp directory on the filesystem, excluding the `.git` directory. Something like `/tmp/diff/new`.
- diff `/tmp/diff/new` with `/tmp/diff/old`
- if the only difference between the two temp directories is the file `foo`, then copy `/tmp/diff/old/foo` to the working directory
- delete `/tmp/diff/old`
- rename `/tmp/diff/new` to `/tmp/diff/old`

It sounds like a huge kludge, but at this moment I can't come up with a better (faster) way.

Anyway, as a team we decided that we are going to keep the commits that only change `foo`. It's for a private repository that will never leave the company, so a bit of cruft is acceptable. We would have higher standards if it were ever to be pushed to GitHub.

(I may turn this edit into an answer at a later time.)

Comment: Have a look at `$(git --exec-path)/git-filter-branch`: it's a huge shell script. You can see what it runs to execute your supplied tree filter (search for `filter_tree`). Note that it's `eval`-ed so you must be very careful with quoting.

Comment: I did and I curled up in a little corner to cry. Fortunately for me a change was made to the filter script (collaborative effort, I don't know exactly what my colleague changed) which resulted in no more commits with only changes to `foo`, so this question is no longer relevant, except for curiosity.